# Entity Framework - Inheritance Null Value

Tags: database, entity-framework, null

I want the following database table:

> [Id] [BookType] [Hardcover]

But only when booktype is 1, hardcover may not be null. So whenever booktype is 2 or 3 I should be able to give a null value to hardcover.

Is there anything in my database where I can set this kind of rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hardcover column must accept null to support type 2 and 3. It is application rule not database rule. You must validate in the application that entity with book type = 1 always has a value set to  hardcover.

If you defined inheritance and you have separate type for book of type 1 you can try to make Hardcover property non nullable in the model (but it will most probably don't work with the code first approach).

Comment: I'm using model first at the moment. I already got inheritance so I'll try to make it not nullable for the subtype. Thanks!